# Facing Action failed: aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth error in IE11 but works in Edge,Chrome and Firefox

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am facing below error in IE11 and I am not able figure out what could be causing this issue.

`SCRIPT5022: Action failed: aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth [Syntax error]
aura_prod_compat.js (13,15)`

Is this because of `<aura:if>` or render expression in `<div class={!\\renderExpression}>`

Comment: Ie11 is not a browser that is recommended, check lightning browser support

Comment: @glls Yes,I understand this point, but it is more from the point of performance issues, i.e. more time to load page in IE. But, I don't know if IE can throw such errors .

Comment: Happy to help, but are you able to isolate the problem and provide relevant pieces for us to replicate? Without it we are shooting in the dark. That said, the message aura:if$controller$handleTheTruth is suggesting that aura:if is the prime suspect, because when the value of isTrue in aura:if is changed a controller action named c.handleTheTruth is fired. Check to see if you have a complex condition in isTrue with dynamic attributes? If so, try breaking it down piece by piece to isolate the issue. If that doesn't work, does isTrue="true" (hardcoding) work at all?

Comment: I will post code details in the question and also try with hardcoding. But as of now, `isTrue` logic is simple: `<aura:if isTrue="{!v.bolVar}" >`. `bolvar` is a boolean attribute which get sets to `true` on `init`.

Comment: Doesn't look good. Have you tried `isTrue="{!1==1}"` just to rule out any other weirdness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller.js was using spread functions and IE11 does not support ES6 spread functions. So, to resolve the issue, spread function was converted into array in some other function.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something that is not supported by IE11, in my case '=>' this operator in controller.js was causing this issue.

Comment: As I answered earlier, we were using spread functions which is not supported in IE11.